# How to select an element placed at unknown level

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have :

```
<div class=mystyle>
    <input type=checkbox>
    <div>
      <div>  <!---<< the label can be inside here--->
        <div>  <!---<< or here--->
         .....  <<!---< or ????--->
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

I have a `label` element for that `input`

Is there any way to create a css selector to select it (the `label`) no matter where it is?.

Comment: `.mystyle label { ........ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.mystyle label{}` this works for every label within your mystyle-classed-div.

Comment: sorry everybody, I have edited the post to clarify my question. I want to do this when I have a checked state

Answer (score 0):

See here:
I have made 3 selectors for you.

If you want different styling on different labels, and all are inside the div.mystyle you can add class="unique-class" for each label.

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/gcxsaqw2/1/

```
<div class=mystyle>
    <input type=checkbox>
    <div>
      <div>  <label class="one">One</label>
        <div>  <label>Two</label>
        <label>Three</label>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {background-color:yellow;}
.mystyle label {background-color:blue;}
label.one {background-color:red;}
```

Comment: In the CSS I made 3 different selectors. The order of them affects the output. In the fiddle you can experiment yourself. :-)